# Fill Down Conditional Formatting Custom Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet that has 4 columns and 200 rows. I want to check that columns 3&4 are equal (numbers), if not highlight that row yellow. I'm using the following:

Apply to Range
B6:E6
Format cells if...
Custom formula is

```
=$D6<>$E6
```

How do I configure the formula or "copy-paste" that function of the formula down to say row 200?

Each row must compare cells D (of say row 7,8,9,100,101) with cells E (of say row 7,8,9,100,101).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the last `6` from the range `B6:E6`:

[image: 0]